# Vuejs : is it possible to name Vue instances in vue-devtools?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-devtools

I'm implementing a web page with multiple Vue instances.

I have a simple question : is it possible to name and display them under their name with vue-devtools?

Actually my console displays instances like this and it is hard to distinguish them :

[image: vue-devtools]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By "multiple instances of Vue", if you mean you have multiple `new Vue({})` instances, then you can give each its own name as:

```
new Vue({
  name: 'Samayo'
})
```

And now the `<Root>` in your devtools will be replaced with `<Samayo>`

Comment: This is exactly it

Answer (score 0):

For [Vue.js 3](https://v3.vuejs.org/)

```
createApp({
  name: 'someName',
  // ...
})
```